# Installing the library "IGRAPH" for C/C++ in application folder

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, igraph

Problem installing the library "IGRAPH" for C/C++ in application folder

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04

Download link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/igraph/?source=dlp

I'm trying to install the library "IGRAPH" for C / C + + based on this link:

http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/html/igraph-installation.html

http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/html/ch03s01.html

http://www.linphone.org/docs/mediastreamer2/mediastreamer2_install.html see section "Installation Names"

Basic, To install the complete C library typing

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install
```

By default, `'make install'` installs the package's commands under `/usr/local/bin`, include files under `/usr/local/include`, etc. I want install the package's in my application directory

I modified the default installation so:

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install DESTDIR=~/Desktop/Graph/igraph/
```

I'm trying compile the following short example program:

```
#include "../usr/local/include/igraph/igraph.h"

int main(void) {
    igraph_integer_t diameter;
    igraph_t graph;
    igraph_erdos_renyi_game(&graph, IGRAPH_ERDOS_RENYI_GNP, 1000, 5.0/1000, IGRAPH_UNDIRECTED, IGRAPH_NO_LOOPS);
    igraph_diameter(&graph, &diameter, 0, 0, 0, IGRAPH_UNDIRECTED, 1);
    printf("Diameter of a random graph with average degree 5: %d\n", (int) diameter);
    igraph_destroy(&graph);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling the program using the command:

```
gcc igraph_test.c -I~/Desktop/Graph/igraph/usr/local/include/igraph -L~/Desktop/Graph/igraph/usr/local/lib -ligraph -o igraph_test
```

But, this error occurs:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ligraph
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is that the actual code you're compiling, and the actual error it gives? Or does your real code say `GRAPH_UNDIRECTED` on line 8, when it should (probably) say `IGRAPH_UNDIRECTED`?

Comment: Sorry, The error was another. Fix question.

Comment: Have you checked that the installation did put the library where you expect it? I.e. is there a `libigraph.a` or `.so` in `~/Desktop/Graph/igraph/usr/local/lib`?

Comment: Yes, all files are in this directory.
There is: ~/Desktop/Graph/igraph/usr/local/lib e ~/Desktop/Graph/igraph/usr/local/include/igraph

Comment: I tried `pkg-config --libs --cflags ~/Desktop/Graph/igraph/usr/local/include/igraph`, but not work.

Comment: Work \o/. I'm modified args build: `gcc igraph_test.c -I../usr/local/include/igraph/ -L../usr/local/lib/ -ligraph -o igraph_test`. But, I think that `../usr/local/include/igraph/` is equal the `~/Desktop/Graph/igraph/usr/local/include/igraph`. 
I do not understand.

Comment: I must remove the post?

Answer (score 1):

When you are invoking `gcc`, try to spell out the full name of your home directory (e.g., `/Users/whatever/Desktop/Graph/igraph/usr/local/lib`) instead of simply specifying `~/Desktop/Graph/igraph/usr/local/lib`. Do the same for `~/Desktop/Graph/igraph/usr/local/include`. This solves the problem for me on my machine.